# Why do I get [object XMLHttpRequest] when using Dajaxice in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest, dajaxice

HI I am creating an app in Django. I am currently using to Dajaxice in order to render a random CODE.

I cannot access my python function when I try pass some variables to it. Independently of what I do, I get as a result [object XMLHttpRequest].

This is my javascript code in my html site:

```
function valid_discount2(){
    var cell = document.getElementById('phone_number').value;
    var code = Dajaxice.chocolate.chocolate.cellphone(cell);
    alert ("CODE = " + code);
}
```

python code in ajax.py:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from random import randint

@dajaxice_register
def cellphone(request, cell):
    random_number = randint(1000,9999)
    code = cell + str(random_number)
    return simplejson.dumps({'code':code})
```

I realize that if I just erase cell from  `def cellphone(request, cell)` [namely, `def cellphone(request)` ], I can access the the function cellphone(request).

However, I still get [object XMLHttpRequest] as a result. (I of course define cell with another variable inside the function cellphone(request))

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use Dajax at the end. If it is of any help for someone, here is my solution:

ajax.py:

```
    @dajaxice_register(method = 'GET')
    def cellphone(request, cell):
        dajax = Dajax()
        random_number = randint(1000,9999)
        code = cell + str(random_number)
        dajax.assign('#code','value', code))
        return dajax.json()
```

javascript code:

```
function valid_discount2(){
dajaxice.chocolate.chocolate.cellphone(Dajax.process,{'cell':$('#phone_number').val()})
}
```

I show the 'code' in an input with id=#code instead of showing it in the alert box.